# TSLint: Warning: The 'no-use-before-declare' rule requires type checking

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I'm working on a medium sized Angular 4 project which uses TSLint.

Every time I run the lint command with `npm run lint` (which uses `ng lint`) I see a warning in the command line:

> Warning: The 'no-use-before-declare' rule requires type checking

I've tried to enable type-checking by adding the `--type-check` and `--project path/to/the/tsconfig.json` file which is apparently "*all you need to do*"™, but whatever I do, the warning is still shown in the console (as if the flags are not having any effect).

There are no lint issues in the project, regardless of whether I use the `--type-check` and `--project` flags or not.

Is type-checking being enabled? Should the warning go away?

#### Edit

The problem is with passing the flags from the command-line to the `ng lint` command:

If I run the command on the command line like this:

```
npm run lint --type-check --project tsconfig.json
```

Then I still see the warning on the command line. If I update the command in the package.json to this:

```
"lint": "ng lint --type-check --project tsconfig.json",
```

Then the warning message is *not* shown in the console, and I get a couple of extra lints.

Comment: `ng lint --type-check` works fine for me with rules that require type checking. What version of `@angular/cli` are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.3.1

Comment: Ahh, the problem is with passing the flags to the command, I'll update the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was only with passing flags from command line to the `ng lint` command. I fixed it using this command from the command line:

```
npm run lint -- --type-check
```

Just needed the extra `--` to pass the flag through correctly

Answer (score 2):

A quick update to this answer:

TSlint outputs now
`--type-check is deprecated. You only need --project to enable rules which need type information.`
when using --type-check.